# error installing google chrome on mint 16

Tags: google-chrome

this is how it is shown in the terminal

```
adarsh@adarsh-desktop ~ $ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for adarsh: 
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 145305 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from .../google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/google/chrome/locales/tr.pak' to '/opt/google/chrome/locales/tr.pak.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

pls help
i am new to linux. i tried all sorts of methods.

Answer (score 1):

**The terminal gives information needed to fix this**, if you read the last few lines. . .

```
unexpected end of file or stream Errors were encountered while processing: Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

The Downloaded `.deb` file is probably **corrupt** (/incomplete) and you may need a new one for a fresh install.
Now you may complete the installation in two ways:

1. Download the `.deb` file again from the the website and install it through the terminal

   sudo dpkg -i PACKAGE_NAME.deb
2. Download the `.deb` file again from the the website and use a package installer such as *[App-grid](http://www.appgrid.org/)* or *Ubuntu Software Center* or *gdebi* for GUI based installation.

---

**You can do the whole process of downloading, installing and launching Google Chrome again using this one line on your Lunix machine**

```
cd /tmp && wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb && sudo apt-get -f install && google-chrome
```

the above line does 5 things:

1. Changes directory to /tmp folder.
2. Downloads latest version of Google Chrome browser (32bit).
3. installs the downloaded Google Chrome package.
4. installs missing dependencies.
5. launches google-chrome once installed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason is the lack of memory. For example, the same error occurred if you try to install chrome on AWS EC2 `t3.nano` which has 0.5GB of memory. You should change the type of instance in this case.

Comment: Thank @wirekang! You saved me.